# Title :post data as application/x-www-form-urlencoded in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, api

I'm building an API for my project and I want to encode and Post the parameters in the URL (not as Json) to other server. I used to use WebRequest in standard .Net versions but now I'm using Asp.Net core 2.2
Is there any Nuget for this task ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [refit client](https://github.com/reactiveui/refit) nuget package. It saves your time,